# How to print a GoogleMap (or any div)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser, printing, html2canvas

I would like to print the google map (not the rest of the page) of my website, It shall include markers, polyline, infoWindows.

The common way is to use `window.print()` but this prints the entire page, is there any way to only print a specific map or div?

I've seen people hiding the entire page except the rendered div but that seems overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this using a combination of [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) and popout :

First, I use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) to render the GoogleMap (or the div to be rendered).

Then I open a new window with the size of the map or the div, I add an img tag inside the window and I give the canvas URI (rendered in the first step) as the image data .

Finally, I print the popup with `window.print()` and then close the popout.

Here is my js function(including [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) lib):

```
function printDiv(divId){
    // For GoogleMaps I ignore the helps messages (.gm-style-pbc) displayed over the GoogleMap
    $(".gm-style-pbc").each(function(){this.setAttribute("data-html2canvas-ignore","true");});
    html2canvas($('#'+divId), 
    {
    useCORS: true, // useCORS for GoogleMap or divs that use resources from outside the website
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
            // Can be tweaked to avoid popout being blocked
            var myWindow=window.open("about:blank","popup"," width="+canvas.width+", height="+ canvas.height + "resizable=0,scrollbar=0");
            if (myWindow == null){
                //If popout has been blocked display a error message here
            }else{
                //Creating empty window with rendred div image URI
                var content = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
                content += "<html><head><title>Map</title></head><body>"
                content += "<img src="+canvas.toDataURL()+"></img>"
                content += "</body></html>"
                myWindow.document.open()
                myWindow.document.write(content);
                myWindow.document.close();
                myWindow.focus();
                //Added a 500 ms timer before printing and closing as GoogleChrome sometimes didnt had time to render the image and printed a blank screen
                setTimeout(function(){myWindow.print();myWindow.close();},500);
            }
      }
    });
  }
```

A few notes:

- The render of the GoogleMap isn't perfect as html2canvas doesn't support webkit transformation.
- Even with useCORS on, if connection to map API is slow, googlemap background may be incomplete (use html2canvas proxy if you encounter this issue)
- Popout can be blocked and have to be allowed manually by the user (especially on Firefox from my experience)

A screenshot of my french app for the sake of it:

[image]